# How do you highlight an edge with a material?

Tags: rendering, edges, intersection

I have two solids that intersect (one red, the other green). I would like render them both  slightly transparently so I can see all the edges and would I'd also like to highlight the edges that lie on both of them. So far I only have the two colored solids like this:

[image]

Where as I want to render something like this (note the orange line highlighting the edges of intersection):

[image]